# updating GUI status bar from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, delegates, callback

I have one application developed in C# and one C# dll which i am using for serial communication. 
after every 10 seconds i want to update the GUI from dll and want to send  status message from dll  to the Main program.

callback maybe the option for this. but not able to write it correctly.

It will be great if someone can give me proper syntax.

Comment: Events will not be enough for this?

Comment: The classes in your DLL must expose **events** which your GUI registers handlers on.

Comment: will be great if you can provide me the syntax/sample code for this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a delegate:

```
    public class SerialReader
    {
        public Action<string> Callback;

        public void Read()
        {
            if (Callback != null)
                Callback("Here is a message for the status bar");

        }
    }
```

Which the GUI class registers for:

```
    public class GuiClass
    {
        public void foo() {

            var reader = new SerialReader();
            reader.Callback = UpdateStatusBar;

        }

        public void UpdateStatusBar(string message) {
            statusBar.Text = message;
        }

    }
```

Make sure the Callback is set somewhere in your GUI code:

```
reader.Callback = UpdateStatusBar;
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.. this was something exactly i was looking for.. but after implementing the same code in my application i found          if (Callback != null) is never set to true so the function in my main application is never get called,.. is that something i am missing to instantiate.

Comment: as per your instruction i already set it but still not working..:)  just for your information please note serialReader class is in dll (Implemented in C#) and GUI is my main application.. this may help you to diagnose my problem..

Comment: It does not matter that they are in different dll's/exe. Try calling the function manually right after you set it: reader.Callback = UpdateStatusBar; reader.Callback("test message");

Comment: if i am not wrong than you mean i have to call the function from my GUI Class to DLL, but what if i want to to call function from my dll to my main program. It may be very basic question to ask but i am newbie to c# so your help will be greatly appreciated..!

Comment: Call it from the gui, just to make sure it gets set. If it is set then you should be able to call it from your dll as well

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, it get set and when i call it from gui i can see the result.. but how can i make the same call from dll

Comment: from with dll, just call Callback("Another message"), if Callback is null you have not set it correctly, perhaps you can update your questions with some code samples from the GUI and the Dll

Comment: it worked .. my silly mistake was there. thanks for showing passions to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

So this is just an example. First, the code from your DLL which exposes an event.

```
class MyWorkerClass
{
  public event EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs> Changed;

  void OnChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
  { 
     if (Changed != null) Changed(this, args);
  }

  public void DoWork(object state)
  {
     // do your work
     OnChanged(new ProgressChangedEventArgs(50, state);   // use percentage
  }
}
```

And the code in your GUI.

```
public class MyGUI
{
   readonly MyWorkerClass worker;

   public MyGUI()
   {
      this.worker = new MyWorkerClass();
      this.worker.Changed += OnWorkerChanged;
   }

   public void OnWorkerChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
   {
      // ToDo: use args.ProgressPercentage to update a GUI element (example: ProgressBar)
      // Remark: make sure you are in the GUI thread. Use this.InvokeRequired to check
   }
}
```

Comment: Fine ;) glad it helped. Please accept the answer then.

Comment: Just tried to implement your solutions but Changed is always null so callback is not executing.., is that something i am missing to instantiate..